# 404 issue after spring migration from 3.x to 4.2.3.Release

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We migrated spring project from 3.2.3.Release to 4.2.3.Release, we are facing 404 issue due to context path missing, it was working good with 3.2.3.Release

```
<form:form action="/planning/plan"> - current snippet in 3.2.3.Release
but after migration it is expecting  contextpath as prefix like below
<form:form action="testabc/planning/plan"> testabc is context path
```

what is the issue can any one please suggest what is the reason
  below is the list of jars we are using, what is the issue do we really need to append the context path

```
activation-1.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-4.2.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
biarengine-12.3.6.1006.jar
biplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
boconfig-12.3.6.1006.jar
cafinstall-12.3.6.1006.jar
cecore-12.3.6.1006.jar
celib-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_client-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_core-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_cr-12.3.6.1006.jar
cereports-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesdk-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesearch-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesession-12.3.6.1006.jar
cglib-3.1.jar
classworlds-1.1.jar
clientplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
commons_driver-12.3.6.1006.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-cli-1.0.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
corbaidl-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlov-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlovexternal-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlovmanifest-12.3.6.1006.jar
CrystalCommon2-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom_chart_lib_en-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom_chart_lib-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom-12.3.6.1006.jar
dfc.jar
doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
ebus405-12.3.6.1006.jar
ehcache-core-2.6.10.jar
elf-1.0.jar
i18n4j-12.3.6.1006.jar
itext-1.4.5-12.3.6.1006.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar
jsch-0.1.27.jar
jsse.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
jtools-12.3.6.1006.jar
jxl-2.6.jar
jxlib-12.3.6.1006.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
logging-12.3.6.1006.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar
maven-core-2.0.6.jar
maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar
maven-filtering-1.0.jar
maven-model-2.0.6.jar
maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar
maven-profile-2.0.6.jar
maven-project-2.0.6.jar
maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
maven-repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar
maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
maven-settings-2.0.6.jar
mybatis-3.2.3.jar
mybatis-ehcache-1.0.3.jar
mybatis-spring-1.2.1.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
rasapp-12.3.6.1006.jar
rascore-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean.fc-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean.wi-12.3.6.1006.jar
ReportViewer-12.3.6.1006.jar
serialization-12.3.6.1006.jar
SL_plugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.11.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.11.jar
spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jmx-2.0.8.jar
spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
sunjce_provider.jar
URIUtil-12.3.6.1006.jar
wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar
webreporting-12.3.6.1006.jar
wilog-12.3.6.1006.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

can any one suggest does spring 4.x

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<c:url var="planUrl" value="/planning/plan" />
<form:form action="${planUrl}">
```

or

```
<form:form action="<c:url value="/planning/plan" />">
```